# Foursquare venue search: limit issue

Tags: foursquare

I am playing around reqursive venue collecting, requesting api with this:

```
def VenueSearch(sw,ne,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET):
   global requests, json
   baseUrl = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/searchsw=%s&ne=%s&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&intent=browse" % (sw, ne, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)

payload = {'sw':sw,
            'ne':ne,
            'client_id':CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret':CLIENT_SECRET,
            'intent':'browse',
            'v':'20140723',
            'limit':50
            }
```

somehow request started to ALWAYS returns 50 venues, no matter inside or near bounding box. How can I cure this? I need to get venues strictly inside bbox, or I have to re-check positions on my side?

Answer (score 0):

So the only solution is to also check **Explore** endpoint if the result is smaller than 50 venues